# How to stop omxplayer from a JavaFX application?

Tags: raspbian, java, omxplayer

I'm firing OMXplayer from a JavaFX app and I need to stop the video when a certain event occurs. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the way I start OMX

```
Process Builder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "omxplayer -o hdmi " + path);
Process process = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start looking at the Process.getOutputStream() method (more details, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), and pass the usual OMXPlayer commands into that stream (like 'q' for quit). If that doesn't work, you might need to look at the way you invoke OMXPlayer from ProcessBuilder - you either need to work with pipes or need to find a way to directly invoke OMXPlayer instead of running it as an argument to bash.

You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389648/how-to-open-and-close-omxplayer-python-raspberry-pi-while-playing-video to see how the Answer provided answers the same problem in Python - principle should be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Phil B. I used the Process.getOutputStream() method and it worked nicely!!!